# Object iteration and comparison not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The following code for solving anagrams works with ES6 (commented) way of iterating through object and comparing `aCharMap` with `bCharMap` but doesn’t with ES5 code example.

Why is the code behaving differently when using ES5 version or am I missing something?

```js
function anagrams(stringA, stringB) {
  const aCharMap = buildCharMap(stringA);
  const bCharMap = buildCharMap(stringB);

  if (Object.keys(aCharMap).length !== Object.keys(bCharMap).length) {
    return false;
  }

  //  for (let char in aCharMap) {
  //    if (aCharMap[char] !== bCharMap[char]) {
  //      return false;
  //    }
  //  }

  Object.keys(aCharMap).forEach(function(char) {
    if (aCharMap[char] !== bCharMap[char]) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  return true;
}

function buildCharMap(str) {
  const charMap = {};

  for (let char of str.replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase()) {
    charMap[char] = charMap[char] + 1 || 1;
  }

  return charMap;
}

console.log(anagrams('one one', 'two two two'));
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? What does 'doesnt work' mean?

Comment: You can't `return` from within a `.forEach()`.